# Oracle SQL help I need to count number of tickets for specific team member of a group

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I need to create a report based on the following SQL query, the conditions are:
They need to be Assigned to QASP Team
Also the Status has to be Resolved or Closed, this part works but when I need to add another filter which is the Team Member in specific, it doesn't show me just his tickets.

```
select count(*) as Tickets, assigned_to from mytable 
WHERE resolved_grp = 'QASP'
and status = 'Resolved' or status = 'Closed'
group by assigned_to
```

I have over 500 members on this table, but i just need a few like: member47, member15, member302
So I need to create 1 report based on those specific members.
Any idea guys?

Comment: Can you add some sample data to the question? When issues are resolved, do they get reassigned away from the specific team member?

Comment: Nope, but they have a field "Resolved_by" that I can use too

Comment: And the sample data...?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select count(*) as Tickets, assigned_to from mytable 
WHERE resolved_grp = 'QASP'
and status in ('Resolved', 'Closed')
and assigned_to in ('member47', 'member15', 'member302')
group by assigned_to
```

Comment: Im not getting any results with this

Answer (score 1):

Try adding parentheses around your OR logic:

```
WHERE resolved_grp = 'QASP'
and ( status = 'Resolved' or status = 'Closed' )
```

Then add your other condition.  You may have been picking up other tickets just because they were in Closed status.

Comment: Im not getting anything either